# Disable pan in UIScrollView on pinch by 2 fingers

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to stop scrolling after detect second touch and handle touches with my own pinch gesture.
I've tryed this in scroll view:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(event.allTouches.count > 2)self.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(event.allTouches.count > 2)self.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
}
```

But it's doesnt works.

Try this:

`scroll.panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;`

But nothing

Comment: I found 1 error. Simple change ">" to "==", and all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution. I redefined UIScrollView, and add:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

And disable\enable pan gesture:

```
if(pinch.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) scroll.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO; 
if(pinch.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) scroll.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
```

Now my pinch gesture works.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable scroll View using like this  :

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

       if ([touches count] == 2) {

       //Disable scrollview 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `delayContentTouches` property of `UIScrollView` to NO (instead of the default YES). This will allow the touch to propagate to the `subviews` of the scroll view immediately.

Comment: I add pinch to UIScrollView, not to internal view. Sorry for my english, if I was not able to convey the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting the enabled property of UIPangestureRecognizer didn't work, at least in my code. However, setting the UIScrollView's scrollEnabled property has worked for me.

```
scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = true;
```

Comment: This disables panning, but if they pinch they can still pan while pinching

Answer (score 0):

After 10 years, I have got the answer.

UIScrollView sets itself as delegate, then:

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard pinchCenter != .zero else { return }
    contentOffset.x = pinchStartContentOffset.x - (pinchCenter.x - pinchStartContentOffset.x) * (zoomScale / pinchStartScale - 1)
    contentOffset.y = pinchStartContentOffset.y - (pinchCenter.y - pinchStartContentOffset.y) * (zoomScale / pinchStartScale - 1)
    pinchStartScale = zoomScale
    pinchStartContentOffset = contentOffset
}

var pinchCenter: CGPoint = .zero
var pinchStartScale: CGFloat = 0
var pinchStartContentOffset: CGPoint = .zero

func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?) {
    guard pinchGestureRecognizer?.numberOfTouches ?? 0 >= 2 else { return }
    guard
        let p1 = pinchGestureRecognizer?.location(ofTouch: 0, in: self),
        let p2 = pinchGestureRecognizer?.location(ofTouch: 1, in: self)
    else { return }
    pinchCenter = CGPoint(x: -((p1.x + p2.x) / 2 - bounds.origin.x),
                          y: -((p1.y + p2.y) / 2 - bounds.origin.y))
    pinchStartScale = zoomScale
    pinchStartContentOffset = contentOffset
}
```